# Help needed identifying SMD component (capacitor? power switching diode?)

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, component-failure

Any help is appreciated!

I though it could be power switching diode but confused with no cathode marking or a capacitor. The device turns on intermittently (1 out 100 reset attempts).

Shape: cylindrical
Seems that external part is plastic. It is white/beige in color.
Dimensions: L ~3.9mm, Diameter ~1.9mm
[image]

[image: unknown component]

[image: unknown component2]

Added another picture with better focus:

[image]

I've de-soldered and cut the component in half. Here is correspondig picture:

[image: cross section view]

Comment: Try posting a picture in focus and state what the circuit board comes from.

Comment: @Andyaka Hello Andy! The board measures torque and sends it over wireless (cycling cranks).

Comment: Can you get an in-focus version of the second picture? That one seems most useful for identifying what's going on with the circuit there.

Comment: From the fuzzy view it looks like a MELF package probably a diode.

Comment: @Gil I would agree - MELF package of power switching diode (area of the circuit respondible for power-up with a LED near by - as well as capacitor and voltage regulator). But there are absolutely no marking to make out cathode end - so can not exclude capacitor in MELF package.

Comment: @Hearth I've added another picture. Thank you for looking.

Comment: @Gil - another idea is bi-directional TVS diode - but absolutely no markings

Answer (score 2):

Possible it's a MELF gas discharge tube, if the manufacturer was really worried about lighting etc. [Eg. this typical one](https://www.meritekusa.com/products/gdt-and-spark-gaps/gdt-smd/mgt5-2-series-gas-discharge-tubes/):

[image]

---

Based on comments and more details of the part and of the application, I suspect it's a MELF tilt detector similar to [this](https://signalquest.com/product/components/sq-sen-815b/) type.

[image]

Comment: Hello! I've attached the cross-section magnified view of the cut component. The circuit is 3V. The (outside) gray is plastic.

Comment: Inconclusive to me. But I wonder if it's a position sensor with a ball bearing shorting the pins. Does the PCB rotate?

Comment: It does rotate but position pickup is from strain gauges. a position sensor would have three leads right? no ball bearings.

Comment: Not a precision sensor, or a strain gauge torque sensor. It could be something to cause the circuit to wake up when it notices that it is rotating. You have a better idea whether that's possible, knowing the functionality.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for clarification. Would it have only 2 pins?

Comment: Yes, for example [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/173) part.

Comment: Thank you again for your suggestion. There were no moing parts inside.

Comment: Can exclude a fuse or a tilt sensor. On the second crank arm, this component does not chage conductivity based on tilt angle / PCB orientation.